# After refresh my radio inputs aren't disabled as they're sent from server

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, radio-button

First I'm sorry for my English.
Next I have a problem. I'm using CodeIgniter 2 and I create two disabled radio buttons with form helper. When I ask for the page directly from the server, buttons are disabled, everything is ok. After some actions they become enabled, but when I refresh (F5 or browser button or Ctrl+R), the first radio comes back disabled but the other one isn't and it stays active and it can crash my system. I know there is difference if I type URL in address bar and press enter (where I haven't such a problem) and refreshing with F5 and refreshing with Ctrl+F5, but I don't know how to do it in right way. I hope somebody could help me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I understood your question correctly. Perhaps you can improve your question by including code samples and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php $formData = array(
    'radio' => array(
        'article' => array(
            'name' => 'whatToAdd',
            'value' => '0',
            'id' => 'article',
            'class' => 'whatToAdd',
            'disabled' => '1',
        ),
        'categories' => array(
            'name' => 'whatToAdd',
            'value' => '1',
            'id' => 'category',
            'class' => 'whatToAdd',
            'disabled' => '1',
        ),
    ),
)?>
<?php echo form_radio($formData['radio']['article'])?>
<?php echo form_radio($formData['radio']['categories'])?>
```

When I open the page for the first time everything is ok - there are two disabled radios. After selecting some values, they become enabled with javascript's jquery library:

```
$('input.whatToAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Everthing is ok. Now I can select one of them and the AJAX will be send. The problem is when I hit F5, the second radio button continues to be enabled after refreshing and it really can crash my code. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender[]" id="gender1" value="1" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender[]" id="gender2" value="2" />FeMale
```

Use the above code to create a .html file and run it. It also works in the same way. I hope this is not an issue, it is HTML a property.

Comment: The problem I have is only in Firefox, I fixed it, thanks for everyone helped there :)